# SQL return only rows where value exists multiple times and other value is present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this in MS SQL SERVER

```
+------+------+
|  ID  | Cust |
+------+------+
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  B   |
|   3  |  A   |
|   3  |  B   |
|   3  |  B   |
|   3  |  C   |
|   3  |  C   |
+------+------+
```

I don't know the values in column "Cust" and I want to return all rows where the value of "Cust" appears multiple times and where at least one of the "ID" values is "1".
Like this:

```
+------+------+
|  ID  | Cust |
+------+------+
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  A   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   1  |  B   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  A   |
|   2  |  B   |
|   3  |  A   |
|   3  |  B   |
|   3  |  B   |
+------+------+
```

Any ideas? I can't find it.

Comment: what have you tried so far? got any code as a starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `COUNT` window function as the following:

```
SELECT ID, Cust 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, Cust, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust) cn,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ID=1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust) cn2
   FROM table_name
  ) T
WHERE cn>1 AND cn2>0
ORDER BY ID, Cust
```

`COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust)` to check if the *value of "Cust" appears multiple times*.

`COUNT(CASE WHEN ID=1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust)` to check that *at least one of the "ID" values is "1"*.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BLyOA_bI).